# Unit test in python is not working despite jupyter notebook working fine

Tags: python, pandas, unit-testing, testing

I am having trouble running a test on my .py script which basically just creates a mapping file (takes 3 datasets and merges them). Every time I run the test in the terminal, it fails and I don't know what I am doing wrong because when I run it in jupyter notebook, it works.

Here is what I have (not working):

```
import unittest
from pandas.util.testing import assert_frame_equal
from create_mapping_file import *


def main():
        PATH_ARCHIVED_ENSEMBLS = 'test-data/original_files/archived_emsembls.txt'
        PATH_ARCHIVED_ACCESSIONS = 'test-data/original_files/archived_accessions.txt'
        PATH_UNIPROT_MAPPING = 'test-data/original_files/uniprot_name_mapping.dat'
        
        actual = create_mapping_df(PATH1, PATH2, PATH3)
        actual = actual.replace("", np.nan, regex = True)
        
      #  actual.to_csv('expected.csv', index = False) 
      # when I include the above line, the test runs fine, but when I run it the second 
      # time around, it stops working

        expected=pd.read_csv("expected.csv")
        assert_frame_equal(expected.reset_index(drop = True), actual.reset_index(drop = True))
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()
```

Here is the error I am getting. I'm confused for two main reasons: most of the IDs look the exact same--and it claims they are different) There are some IDs that aren't the same and I don't know why they aren't the exact same considering all I did was export the 'actual' and name it 'expected':

```
DataFrame.iloc[:, 3] (column name="Protein ID") values are different (31.16418 %)
[index]: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, ...]
[left]:  [ENSP00000361930, ENSP00000300161, ENSP00000264335, ENSP00000461762, ENSP00000248975, ENSP00000306330, ENSP00000340989, ENSP00000371267, ENSP00000238081, ENSP00000379287, ENSP00000379288, ENSP00000430072, ENSP00000309503, ENSP00000395114, ENSP00000398599, ENSP00000379281, ENSP00000379283, ENSP00000379286, ENSP00000263776, ENSP00000391775, ENSP00000368109, ENSP00000261461, ENSP00000442866, ENSP00000164133, ENSP00000417963, ENSP00000420674, ENSP00000377669, ENSP00000337641, ENSP00000452396, ENSP00000404632, ENSP00000412324, ENSP00000329009, ENSP00000408389, ENSP00000262239, ENSP00000333905, ENSP00000324804, ENSP00000311344, ENSP00000376775, ENSP00000410671, ENSP00000459838, ENSP00000461254, ENSP00000459827, ENSP00000459644, ENSP00000459456, ENSP00000343317, ENSP00000437193, ENSP00000325074, ENSP00000370113, ENSP00000377936, ENSP00000421396, ENSP00000398779, ENSP00000336591, ENSP00000377933, ENSP00000349283, ENSP00000377932, ENSP00000431320, ENSP00000377931, ENSP00000377935, ENSP00000399970, ENSP00000469896, ENSP00000335083, ENSP00000372042, ENSP00000422374, ENSP00000423649, ENSP00000425247, ENSP00000358421, ENSP00000432268, ENSP00000445122, ENSP00000358424, ENSP00000297679, ENSP00000262520, ENSP00000370662, ENSP00000350018, ENSP00000411979, ENSP00000337213, ENSP00000422168, ENSP00000403231, ENSP00000388152, ENSP00000348685, ENSP00000424846, ENSP00000409746, ENSP00000422605, ENSP00000374488, ENSP00000424072, ENSP00000355428, ENSP00000412203, ENSP00000373301, ENSP00000388553, ENSP00000386231, ENSP00000253688, ENSP00000294973, ENSP00000265395, ENSP00000219431, ENSP00000380918, ENSP00000348809, ENSP00000340691, ENSP00000362314, ENSP00000308472, ENSP00000380659, ENSP00000328103, ...]
[right]: [ENSP00000361930, ENSP00000300161, ENSP00000264335, ENSP00000461762, ENSP00000248975, ENSP00000306330, ENSP00000340989, ENSP00000371267, ENSP00000238081, ENSP00000379287, ENSP00000395114, ENSP00000430072, ENSP00000379286, ENSP00000379281, ENSP00000309503, ENSP00000379283, ENSP00000379288, ENSP00000398599, ENSP00000263776, ENSP00000391775, ENSP00000368109, ENSP00000261461, ENSP00000442866, ENSP00000164133, ENSP00000417963, ENSP00000420674, ENSP00000377669, ENSP00000337641, ENSP00000452396, ENSP00000404632, ENSP00000412324, ENSP00000262239, ENSP00000333905, ENSP00000329009, ENSP00000408389, ENSP00000324804, ENSP00000311344, ENSP00000459456, ENSP00000459838, ENSP00000459827, ENSP00000437193, ENSP00000376775, ENSP00000459644, ENSP00000343317, ENSP00000461254, ENSP00000410671, ENSP00000325074, ENSP00000370113, ENSP00000377936, ENSP00000349283, ENSP00000377933, ENSP00000377932, ENSP00000421396, ENSP00000377931, ENSP00000377935, ENSP00000336591, ENSP00000431320, ENSP00000398779, ENSP00000399970, ENSP00000469896, ENSP00000335083, ENSP00000425247, ENSP00000372042, ENSP00000422374, ENSP00000423649, ENSP00000358421, ENSP00000432268, ENSP00000445122, ENSP00000358424, ENSP00000297679, ENSP00000370662, ENSP00000262520, ENSP00000350018, ENSP00000411979, ENSP00000337213, ENSP00000422168, ENSP00000374488, ENSP00000422605, ENSP00000348685, ENSP00000388152, ENSP00000409746, ENSP00000424072, ENSP00000424846, ENSP00000403231, ENSP00000355428, ENSP00000412203, ENSP00000373301, ENSP00000388553, ENSP00000386231, ENSP00000253688, ENSP00000294973, ENSP00000265395, ENSP00000219431, ENSP00000380918, ENSP00000348809, ENSP00000340691, ENSP00000362314, ENSP00000308472, ENSP00000380659, ENSP00000328103, ...]
```

Comment: It's not going to be easy to help you if you don't provide enough code to actually reproduce the error. A guess: does your code depend on the order of items in a dictionary?

Comment: Thank you for your response. I usually include a reproducible code snippet, but my script has around 150 lines and I'm not sure what part of my script is causing the issue (my script doesn't include any dictionaries). If you would be willing to quickly skim my script perhaps in a chat, I would be so appreciative.

Comment: Are they just sorted differently? For example, `ENSP00000379288` occurs at the 11th position in [left] and in the 17th position in the [right]. Maybe your test needs a sort step before the comparison? And the difference is because Python and Pandas or any other package version involved aren't the same in the terminal and your notebook? Have you tried running it as a script from inside the notebook using `%run <script_name>` and seen if that gives same result as in notebook? You may need `%run -i <script_name>`.

Comment: @Wayne I added a sort step and it worked! Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution suggested first was to add a sort step to the test. As they just looked sorted differently, as I pointed out in my comment from Sept 3.

Thinking about it more, you could probably also rely on Python's set math / comparison abilities to check the items included are the same in the test. Consider:

```py
a = ["a","b","c"]
b = ["b","a","c"]

set(a) == set(b)
```

That results in returning `True`.

Of course, if the number of repeated items in the list mattered, use of typecasting to a `set` for the check wouldn't work as it only takes one representative of each item that is duplicated or occurs more than once. Make a list a set and then casting back to a list (if that is indeed the type needed) is a very common idiom in Python to reduce a list to the unique elements.